# Send notofication to firebase by PHP Curl, get success response but no notification delivered

Tags: php, firebase, curl, firebase-cloud-messaging

please help.
My request to firebase looks like this:

```
curl https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send -X POST \
--header "Authorization: key=my-api-key" \
--Header "Content-Type: application/json" \
 -d '
 {
   "to": "firebase-instance-id"
   "notification":{
     "title":"New Notification!",
     "body":"Test"
   },
   "priority":10
 }'
```

And I get response:

```
{
    "multicast_id":7748668110190879774,
    "success":1,
    "failure":0,
    "canonical_ids":0,
    "results":[{
        "message_id":"0:1505463398077072%3f95c2ka3f95c2ca"
    }]
}
```

But I see no added notification in Firebase Console List, nor in phone. Any suggestions? Maybe there are some settings I should change in order to can send notifications from my server through curl? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase is weird, according to their documentation you are sending the correct JSON content but [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH10-SW1) requires a slightly modified format, specifically an "aps" wrapper around the message.

```
"aps" : {
    "alert" : {
        "title" : "Game Request",
        "body" : "Bob wants to play poker",
        "action-loc-key" : "PLAY"
    },
    "badge" : 5
}
```

Try adding Apple's JSON format to your current JSON payload and see how it responds. From there you can adjust your payload to make sure it works for both Android (which is what Firebase's documentation is for) and iOS.

Answer (score 0):

I think you malformed your FCM payload. It's missing a comma (`"firebase-instance-id"`) and the value for priority should be `high`.

```
'{
   "to": "firebase-instance-id",
   "notification":{
     "title":"New Notification!",
     "body":"Test"
   },
   "priority":"high"
 }'
```

Contrary to Chris' answer, don't use the APNs payload format since you're sending it from FCM first.